# How do I disable Chrome from converting pdf documents into text

Tags: google-chrome

Since a recent update, every time I download a .pdf and view it in Google Chrome, the document displays the original content for a brief amount of time, the amount of time required for Chrome to use OCR and pull whatever text it can out of it.

I can then click the link in "This page contains the text automatically extracted from the PDF file myFile.pdf. [Click here for the original](http://notReallyALink.com)." And I get the original back, but it's still pretty annoying!

I can't see anything in Settings...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature (or side effect) of the ChromeVox screen reader extension (current version 45.0.2428.0). If you disable ChromeVox, PDFs will be displayed in their original form.